# How can I sort lines that have same number of fields but different in value of one field uniquely using sort or awk?

Tags: bash, sorting, awk, gnu

I want to characterize lines with equal fields but different in a field value in the same field position, as the same and select only one line.

**Example input**

Let field delimiter be "/"

```
1. abc/def/gh/ij/kl
2. abc/def/gh/ij/yi
3. abc/def/gh/ij/ti
4  abc/def/gh/hk/kl/oi/uh
5. abc/def/gh/ol/kl/oi/uh
6. abc/def/gh/er/kl/oi/uh
7. abc/def/gh/er/kl
```

Treat lines 1,2,3 as the same and select only 1 line, even though the values of their 5th field are different, they have same value of other fields and have equal field.

Treat lines 4,5,6 as the same and select only 1 line out of them, even though the values of their 4th field are different, they have same value of other fields and have equal field.

Line 6 and 7 are not the same, since they don't have equal number of fields.

**Desired Output**

```
abc/def/gh/ij/kl
abc/def/gh/hk/kl/oi/uh
```

**NOTE** : The list have lines of different field number.

**I tried `sort -u` but it obviously didn't work, since sort does not use delimiter. Can awk achieve this?**

Comment: Are the `1.` `2.` part of the input file? Steps: 1. Preprocess the file with `sed` or `awk` to extract the parts you want to sort on. 2. Sort on that 3. Put all that should be unique in second column. 4. `uniq -f1` 5. Remove second column. `Can awk achieve this?` Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: @Trendingmike: `sort` has option `-t`, with which you can specify a field delimiter, and option `-k`, with which you specify which fields to use. If you want to keep not anarbitrary one of the duplicate lines, but consistently the first one, look at option `-s`.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks, but since all the lines in the file do not have equal fields, I will be difficult to specify a particular field to be used for sorting.

Comment: @KamilCuk 1. 2. are not part of the file. I don't understand your explanation. I have not tried anything with awk yet.

Comment: @Trendingmike : How big is the file to be sorted? Basically, you seem to have to supply your own comparision function, which decides whether two elements are considered equal. This is easiest, if the file to be sorted fits in memory, because most programming languages have a way to do this. I would use, for instance, Ruby, but you can equally use Perl or Python or what else you are familiar with.

Comment: @Trendingmike : If you really **want** to stick with bash and sort, use an approach called [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). You first create a new file with an additional field holding a key which uniquely identifies your unqueness, then sort on this key, and finally get rid of this field in the sorted file. In any case, you need to provide a **definition** of when two lines are considered equal; you have posted so far only examples.

Comment: Can any line be selected amongst the "same" lines, or the first one must be selected?

Comment: If, from line 1,2,3, you only select 1, why do you also select line 7? It has the same qualifications as line 2 and 3, which are skipped.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin Any line can be selected among the same lines.

Comment: @Luuk It doesn't, since the difference in field, fell into another field position.

Comment: Can you define 'field position' ? What is the value for line 1? what for line 2 , etc...

Comment: @user1934428 : 2 lines are considered equal, if; 1. They have the same number of fields. 2. All field values of the lines are the same, except for 1 field value. Guess what you want me to do is, separate all line with same number of fields into a file, then match field values and by field values to find mismatch.

Comment: @Luuk: The 5th field position of line 1 is "kl" while the 5th field position of line 2 is "yi". Since line 1 to 3 has same field value from 1 to 4 and only differ in 5th field. I selected only 1.

Comment: But by this definition, line 1 and line 7 should be considered equal, shouldn't it?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin: You are correct,  line 1 and line 7 are considered equal . I just critically reviewed the example now. Smiles. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Trendingmike Then why are both selected in the output? Shouldn't only one of them have been selected?

Comment: @M.NejatAydin edited.

Comment: what should happen for these three lines: `a/b/c` `z/b/c` `z/x/c`?

Comment: @EdMorton:  That was a mistake, I have corrected that. Thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'/' '!seen[NF]++' file
abc/def/gh/ij/kl
abc/def/gh/hk/kl/oi/uh
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and update your example to include lines for which this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton, Very simple and perfect answer. It solved the puzzle for me smiles.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment, which excludes line 7, this can be done in gawk:

```
gawk -F "/" '
   BEGIN{ a[0][0]=""; }{ if (a[$1$2$3][NF]!=null)
                {
                }
                else {
                        a[$1$2$3][NF]=$0;
                        }
        }
   END{ delete a[0][0]; 
        for(i in a){
        for(j in a[i]) {
                print a[i][j]
        }}
    }' input
```

output:

```
abc/def/gh/ij/kl
abc/def/gh/hk/kl/oi/uh
```

EDIT: Because line 7 needs to be in the result too :

```
#!/bin/bash
gawk -F "/" '
NF!=p{
   delete a[0];
   for(i in a){
        print a[i]
   }
   p=NF;
   delete a;
   a[0]="";
}
{
   if (p==0) p=NF;
   if (a[$1$2$3]==null)
   {
      a[$1$2$3]=$0;
   };
}
END {
  for (i in a) {
          print a[i];
  }
}'
```

output:

```
abc/def/gh/ij/kl
abc/def/gh/hk/kl/oi/uh
abc/def/gh/er/kl
```

(Short) explanation:

`NF!=p` if the number of fields change print the results so far.

`a[$1$2$3]` is the key of the result(s). Now i do see that this does not need to be an array, because i only have max 1 result (per number of fields)

`END{}`  print the last result.

Comment: Can this answer apply to lines with 2 fields and well as lines with 10 fields? Is it just specific to the example above?

Comment: wrt `a[$1$2$3]` - you can't just concatenate fields and create a unique value since `a/bc/d` -> `abcd` and `ab/c/d` - > `abcd`, etc.. You need to use a separator (SUBSEP or FS typically) to make the resulting string unique.

Comment: @EdMorton: actually i can , but you are right with your statement, that it's not completely correct.

Comment: You **can** concatenate fields but you **can't** create a unique value (the 2nd part of my sentence) by doing so :-). How did you get an emoji in your comment?

Comment: Are you sure about the `null` check?

Comment: @karakfa The null check is just a way to check if the item in the array is there, i simply tested 3 lines to see how i could do this, and this one (seem to ) work.

Comment: @EdMorton: I use WIN+. on my Windows system... (Win-key + dot )  [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4534547/windows-10-keyboard-tips-and-tricks)

Comment: @Luuk, try with `notNull`, it will work the same; but this is very unorthodox way of checking it, you probably meant `!($1$2$3 in a)`

Comment: @Luuk `null` in your script is an uninitialized variable (could be named `fluffy` and behave the same) and so has the value `zero-or-null` and so `array[index]==null` just tests for the **value** of `array[index]` being either zero or `""`. To test for a null string specifically would be `array[index]==""` but the way to test for an index being present in an array is `idx in array` rather than `array[idx]!=""` (or conversely `!(idx in array)` vs `array[idx]==""`).

Comment: OK, thanks for the comments. the `=null` was actually a left-over from some more-complex-not-working-tries. I should put more time in reviewing code before i post it ...

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F/ 'function comb(i) {k=""; 
                             for(j=1  ;j<i  ;j++) k=k FS $j; 
                             for(j=i+1;j<=NF;j++) k=k FS $j; 
                             return k}

           !a[$0] {a[$0]; 
                   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(a[comb(i)]) next; 
                   print; 
                   for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[comb(i)]++}' file

abc/def/gh/ij/kl
abc/def/gh/hk/kl/oi/uh
```

in the hash array, check all combination of the fields with one field missing, if not found add all combinations with one field missing.  Also add the full record for trivial cases.

Answer (score 0):

Given your definition of equality in the comment (which really should go into the question instead of the comment), your problem is impossible to solve for mathematical reasons:

For you, two lines are equal, if they differ in at most one field.

Hence, for you `/a/b/c/d == /a/b/c/e`, because they differ in only in the last field. For the same reason, `/a/b/c/e == /a/x/c/e`, because they too differ only in one field (the second one).

But for a set to be sortable, the order relation must be a total order, which means that equality must be transitive. I.e. for any triple X,Y,Z, `X==Y` and `Y==Z` *must imply* that `X==Z`.

Let's set for your case

```
X=/a/b/c/d
Y=/a/b/c/e
Z=/a/x/c/e
```

The requirement for totalorder would require that `X==Z`, i.e. `/a/b/c/d == /a/x/c/e`, but they differ in two fields, not one.